# Remove unwanted class from element

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have an image slider that shows before and after images when the user drags left to right.  The class 'draggable' is added to these images, but also added to my hero images.  I think the elements are autogenerated, but I can't find how or where (I didn't build this, only tasked with fixing it!).  The problem is when the slider is dragged, the hero images drag back and forth as well.  I can't figure out how to eliminate the 'draggable' class from my the elements my hero images are in.

```
// Call & init

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".ba-slider").each(function () {
    var cur = $(this);
    // Adjust the slider
    var width = cur.width() + "px";
    cur.find(".resize img").css("width", width);
    // Bind dragging events
    drags(cur.find(".handle"), cur.find(".resize"), cur);
  });
});

// Update sliders on resize.
// Because we all do this: i.imgur.com/YkbaV.gif
$(window).resize(function () {
  $(".ba-slider").each(function () {
    var cur = $(this);
    var width = cur.width() + "px";
    cur.find(".resize img").css("width", width);
  });
});

function drags(dragElement, resizeElement, container) {
  // Initialize the dragging event on mousedown.
  dragElement
    .on("mousedown touchstart", function (e) {
      dragElement.addClass("draggable");
      resizeElement.addClass("resizable");

      // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
      var startX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      // Get the initial position
      var dragWidth = dragElement.outerWidth(),
        posX = dragElement.offset().left + dragWidth - startX,
        containerOffset = container.offset().left,
        containerWidth = container.outerWidth();

      // Set limits
      minLeft = containerOffset + 10;
      maxLeft = containerOffset + containerWidth - dragWidth - 10;

      // Calculate the dragging distance on mousemove.
      dragElement
        .parents()
        .on("mousemove touchmove", function (e) {
          // Check if it's a mouse or touch event and pass along the correct value
          var moveX = e.pageX ? e.pageX : e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

          leftValue = moveX + posX - dragWidth;

          // Prevent going off limits
          if (leftValue < minLeft) {
            leftValue = minLeft;
          } else if (leftValue > maxLeft) {
            leftValue = maxLeft;
          }

          // Translate the handle's left value to masked divs width.
          widthValue =
            ((leftValue + dragWidth / 2 - containerOffset) * 100) /
              containerWidth +
            "%";

          // Set the new values for the slider and the handle.
          // Bind mouseup events to stop dragging.
          $(".draggable")
            .css("left", widthValue)
            .on("mouseup touchend touchcancel", function () {
              $(this).removeClass("draggable");
              resizeElement.removeClass("resizable");
            });
          $(".resizable").css("width", widthValue);
        })
        .on("mouseup touchend touchcancel", function () {
          dragElement.removeClass("draggable");
          resizeElement.removeClass("resizable");
        });
      e.preventDefault();
    })
    .on("mouseup touchend touchcancel", function (e) {
      dragElement.removeClass("draggable");
      resizeElement.removeClass("resizable");
    });
}
```

[![element console]

[image]
This is what is generated, but not in the source code.

```
<section class="intro-section">
                        <div class="frame">
                            <?php if( have_rows('intro_slide') ): ?>
                            <div class="intro-slider slick-slider">
                                <?php while( have_rows('intro_slide') ): the_row();
                                $title = get_sub_field('title') ? get_sub_field('title') : get_the_title();
                                $text = get_sub_field('text');
                                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                                $image2 = get_sub_field('logo');
                                $icon = get_sub_field('note_icon');
                                $number = get_sub_field('note_number');
                                $note = get_sub_field('note_text');
                                ?>
                                <div class="slide bg-stretch"<?php if($image): ?> style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>);"<?php endif; ?>>
                                    <div class="container-wrap">
                                    <?php if($image2): ?><div class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $image2['url']; ?>" width="227" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>"></div><?php endif; ?>
                                    <div class="text-overlay">
                                        <?php if($title): ?><h1 class="h2"><?php echo $title; ?></h1><?php endif; ?>
                                        <div class="text-block">
                                            <?php echo $text; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Initially I tried just targeting the element and removing the class, but my variable comes up undefined.

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('slick-list');
x.classList.remove('draggable');
```

Im at a bit of a loss here.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Use jQuery: `$(".slick-list").removeClass("draggable")`

Comment: I think that you can avoid draggable class removing this line in drags function: `dragElement.addClass("draggable");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the x deliever you the elements where the class had to be removed.

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('slick-list');
x.classList.forEach(elem =>  {
    elem.classList.remove('draggable');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok

```
document.getElementsByClassName('slick-list')
```

Gives you a list of elements, if you want to change one you have to access a particular index of that array, so

```
x[0].classList.remove('draggable')
```

Comment: Note that x[0] can affect another element in the DOM. It's not specific.

Comment: @Carlos only if that other element has the class name

Comment: There is perhaps more than 1 element where the class should be removed.

Comment: @sascha op didn't mention multiple classes

Comment: Yes, that's why Sascha made it with forEach. That's a big possibility of havind a lot more sliders, and your code will gonna fail if that happens.

Comment: @bluejack not multiple classes but `the hero images ` means for me plural.

Comment: @carlos it's not about failing or not it's about explaining to to OP why the original code didn't work in order to have him think for himself to fix it next time